# Issues on getting past and future month

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

To get previous month for using this code:

```
if (currentmonth > 1) {
    currentmonth = currentmonth - 1;
    Presentmonth.text = (monthArray[currentmonth - 1]);
}
```

To get future month for using this code:

```
if (currentmonth < 12) {
    currentmonth = currentmonth + 1;  
    Presentmonth.text = (monthArray[currentmonth - 1]);
}
```

In my month array

```
monthArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"January", @"February", @"March", @"April", @"May", @"June", @"July"‌​, @"August", @"September", @"October", @"November", @"December", nil];

// Presentmonth.text = [monthArray objectAtIndex:currentmonth];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
Presentmonth.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringFromDate];
```

My question is, consider `May` as current month, then previous is `april` and future is `june`, in my code returns future month is start from `January` which should be `june`. What wrong in my logic ?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: consider this month is current ,then previous is april and future is june,in my code returns future month is start from january

Comment: monthArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"January",@"February",@"March",@"April",@"May",@"June",@"July",@"August",@"September",@"October",@"November",@"December", nil];
      // Presentmonth.text=[monthArray objectAtIndex:currentmonth];
   
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
    NSDate *myDate=[[NSDate alloc]init];
    stringFromDate= [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
   
    Presentmonth.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringFromDate];

Comment: this is my viewdidloadcode

Comment: wrote the above my code inside the uitapgesture recognizer

Comment: please anyone help me?....

Comment: where do you set currentmonth value?

Comment: above this code,used to set current month value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code like following.

```
NSDate *currentDate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    currentDate = [NSDate date];

    Presentmonth.text=[self getCurrentMonth];
}

- (void)previousMonth {
    NSCalendar *cal         = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitMonth
                                     fromDate:currentDate];
    comps.month             -= 1;
    currentDate          = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];

    Presentmonth.text=[self getCurrentMonth];
}

- (void)nextMonth {
    NSCalendar *cal         = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:currentDate];
    comps.month             += 1;
   currentDate          = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];

    Presentmonth.text=[self getCurrentMonth];

}

- (NSString *)getCurrentMonth {
    NSCalendar *cal         = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitMonth
                                     fromDate:currentDate];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    return [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(comps.month-1)];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot.it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are decreasing month index in the `montharray`instead of incrementing. i.e it should be `monthArray[currentmonth+1]` instead of `monthArray[currentmonth-1]`.
//Edit

So, make the below change
// To get previous month for using this code:

```
if (currentmonth>1) {

    currentmonth=currentmonth-1;

    Presentmonth.text=(monthArray[currentmonth]);
}
```

//To get future month for using this code:

```
if (currentmonth<12) {

    currentmonth=currentmonth+1;  

    Presentmonth.text=(monthArray[currentmonth]);
}
```

Comment: put this method but start future month from march

Comment: Thanks,but not working

Comment: Can please try my answer edit..

Comment: Yeah try this,but not correct compared to my output

Answer (score 0):

please try this code for previous months and year

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [offsetComponents setMonth:-
1]; 
    nextdate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];
    today=nextdate;

TopMonthlbl.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
monthLbl.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:nextdate];

NSRange dayRange = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                    rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth forDate:nextdate]
```

Comment: What is that nextdate